# Serpent Algorithm thats implement Cipher

Tags: java, algorithms

How must i change the Standard Implemplementation of the Serpent Algorithm that i can use it with the javax.crypto.CipherInputStream or javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream?

I must implement/extends the Cipher class and when i do it, what must i change?

The Original Implementation of the Serpent Algorithm is here http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/serpent.html

Exist a Implementation of the Serpent Algorithm that's implement Cipher? I found the Java implementation of the Algorithm on the Page of its Creator. The Problem in this is: i can't use it with javax.crypto.CipherInputStream or javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.

I try to use the ObjectOutputStream to write a Configuration File, but i would like to encrypt it with the Serpent Algorithm. The same is with the reading of this Configuration file.

I don't want to use API's like the BouncyCastle and flexiprovider because they create a to heavy boilerplate which i don't need.

What is the best practice to use a finished (final and tested) Algorithm that dont extends/implements Cipher and it should be used in javax.crypto.CipherXxxStream?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Probably too broad to be answerable here.

Comment: The main Problem i have is: what must i do/change when i extend from the Cipher Class to make use of the Serpent Algorithm found on the Website. I can't figure out what i must do to make this Algorithm really usable in Java (yes i can use it the normal way, but the transparent way with stream is much more elegant). The main problem by BouncyCastle etc is that i must delivery the librarys and the SecurityProvider make all kinds of Algorithm available that i dont need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a walkthrough of how to implement a cipher for Java: [Writing your own JCA extensions - a full cipher](http://codeandme.blogspot.com/2013/07/writing-your-own-jca-extensions-full.html)

The key points from the article are:

> **Create key classes**
>
> We will create a Caesar cipher implementation. You could also do ROT13 with it. As ciphers are about encryption/decryption we need some keys. Our key class will be very simple as we just need to store an offset for shifting our letters later on.
>
> Start by creating a new Java Project named com.example.jce.cipher.
>
> **Implement the cipher**
>
> Ciphers are implemented extending CipherSpi (as all JCA extensions extend a WhateverSpi class).
>
> **Create a JCE provider**
>
> As for the digest, we need to usa a provider to register our digest in the JRE.
>
> **Using our provider**
>
> Create a new Java project com.example.jce.cipher.consumer. Create a subfolder libs and store your signed JAR file there. Then add this JAR to the Java Build Path.
>
> Now everything is in place to use our cipher.

The article also mentions that you must have a certificate from Oracle to sign your cipher or the process cannot be completed.